# Is the US passenger attestation form a requirement for subsequent entries into the US?

Tags: usa, multiple-entry, united-airlines, attestation

The US has an entry requirement for UK residents (and other countries) that requires every traveller entering the US to fill in a passenger attestation form.

I had successfully entered the US November last month (having filled in this form) using Delta's online travel-ready form.

I am travelling to the US again in a few days but this time on United Airlines, their travel-ready system on their app already says I've completed the entry form requirements without me actually doing anything.

Is this because the form I last filled out is still valid and is linked to my passport? Or should I ignore the United Airlines app and fill in the form again? If so, is there an online form I can use again or am I required to have a physical copy.

Comment: Are you referring to the ESTA?

Comment: @JonathanReez no, it's a covid requirement for all US-bound travelers. there's a [sample PDF](https://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/pdf/combined-passenger-attestation-p.pdf) on the CDC website but most (all)? carriers have you fill it out electronically.

Comment: @mlc yeah that's what I'm referring about, thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be one of the more bizarre Covid incompetencies. About half of the times I returned to the US this year I have been yelled at for not having this form at check in.

Typically, I was handed a paper form, dutifully filled it out and than took it home without anyone ever looking for or checking it. I still have a nice collection at home "just in case".

Caveat: in this crazy times: whatever happened to me may no happen to you.

Comment: Thank you, sounds like I should follow suit and fill it out as a precaution.

Comment: @Sutton your earlier attestation is clearly no longer valid, because your statement that you had a test within the three days before a flight in November cannot serve as a statement that you had a test within the three days before a flight in late December.  If the travel-ready system is telling you you're travel ready because of the November attestation then there is a fault in the travel-ready system.